# Why wont my stored procedure use the parameters I am passing it? - MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure that will update one column of a table with incremental ascending numbers.

The code I have

```
CREATE DEFINER=`cis23383518`@`192.168.122.1` PROCEDURE `Increment_rows`(IN TheTable VARCHAR(20),IN TheID VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN
DECLARE i INT;
SET i = 0;
UPDATE TheTable 
SET TheID = i,i= i+1;
END
```

I am calling the procedure as follows

```
CALL Increment_rows('Officer','IncidentID');
```

I get the following error: Table cis23383518.TheTable does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

REFINER is not mandatory.

If you are calling the procedure with the same userid that it was created for, just drop it:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `Increment_rows`(IN TheTable VARCHAR(20),IN TheID VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN
DECLARE i INT;
SET i = 0;
UPDATE TheTable 
SET TheID = i,i= i+1;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql will not substitute a table name with the supplied parameter , the update looks for a table called thetable. If you want to supply a table name to the procedure then you will have to build a sql statement and submit for example

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `Increment_rows`;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE  PROCEDURE `Increment_rows`(IN TheTable VARCHAR(20),IN TheID VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN

set @sqlstmt =  concat('UPDATE ', THETABLE, ' SET STATUS =  (SELECT @I:=@I + 1 FROM (SELECT @I:=0) I) ORDER BY ID DESC;');
SELECT @SQLSTMT;
prepare stmt from @sqlstmt;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;

END $$
```

Note the use of a variable to increment the status column.
so given

```
+----+----------+--------+
| id | username | status |
+----+----------+--------+
|  1 | John     |      0 |
|  2 | Jane     |      0 |
|  3 | Ali      |      0 |
|  6 | Bruce    |      0 |
|  7 | Martha   |      0 |
|  8 | Sidney   |      0 |
| 10 | charlie  |      0 |
| 12 | Elisa    |      0 |
| 14 | Samantha |      0 |
| 15 | Hannah   |      0 |
| 16 | Hannah   |      0 |
| 17 | Kevin    |      0 |
| 18 | Kevin    |      0 |
| 19 | Ruth     |      0 |
+----+----------+--------+
14 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> CALL Increment_rows('USERS','INCIDENTID');
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| @SQLSTMT                                                                               |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| UPDATE USERS SET STATUS =  (SELECT @I:=@I + 1 FROM (SELECT @I:=0) I) ORDER BY ID DESC; |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> select id,username,status from users;
+----+----------+--------+
| id | username | status |
+----+----------+--------+
|  1 | John     |     14 |
|  2 | Jane     |     13 |
|  3 | Ali      |     12 |
|  6 | Bruce    |     11 |
|  7 | Martha   |     10 |
|  8 | Sidney   |      9 |
| 10 | charlie  |      8 |
| 12 | Elisa    |      7 |
| 14 | Samantha |      6 |
| 15 | Hannah   |      5 |
| 16 | Hannah   |      4 |
| 17 | Kevin    |      3 |
| 18 | Kevin    |      2 |
| 19 | Ruth     |      1 |
+----+----------+--------+
14 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Note I think your update statement might need a where statement.